# Explicitly link <span> tag to specific </span>

Tags: html

I'm trying to draw boxes around letters to show ngrams in a word.  For example the word test has 3 bigrams, 'te', 'es', 'st'.  As I draw the boxes, I'm varying the padding so that each box is clearly visible.  However, the problem I run into is that I'm opening a `<span>` tag, opening a second `<span>` tag and then trying to close the *first* tag but the second is what actually gets closed.  This results in the following behavior:

[image: current vs desired]

The HTML I have right now

```
<span style='border:3px; padding: 0.1em;'>     t
  <span style='border:3px; padding: 0.2em;'>   e
</span>
    <span style='border:3px; padding: 0.3em;'> s
  </span>                                           t
    </span>
```

**Is there a way to explicitly link a `</span>` to a particular `<span>` to achieve my desired output?**

Here's [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eLh98aoq/1/) of the problem in action.

Comment: HTML DOM elements can't overlap. The DOM si a tree object, where each node only has one parent and the node can be considered to be atomic (it can not be divided into multiple parts or span across other nodes). You should use `CSS` to achieve the overlapping effect (set the widths accordingly).

Comment: Cristy - I've never used CSS to do anything like what I'm wanting to do here - any tips on where to get started?

Comment: You can use the :after pseudo element to create the boxes and set the widths based on the word length maybe

Comment: It's easy to create the look with extra tags but it's only visually, the code does not overlap, if that's ok then you just need to create some extra tags and draw the boxes

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, a `</span>` tag closes the last opened `<span>`.
The elements are nested and can't overlap in the way you suggest.

Here's one solution to group ngrams (actually [bigrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigram)) using JavaScript (jQuery).
It creates absolutely-positioned boxes over the letters.
I made it skip spaces and unigrams.

```js
// select all the elements
var $elements = jQuery('.find_bigrams');

// iterate through the elements
$elements.each(function() {

  // define this element
  var $element = jQuery(this);

  // build an array of characters
  var text = $element.text().split('');

  // initialize padding to zero
  var pad = 0;

  // empty this element
  $element.empty();

  // wrap each character in a span with the class "character"
  // this allows us to find the position of each character
  jQuery.each(text, function(i, character) {
    jQuery('<span>', {
      'class': 'character',
      'text': character
    }).appendTo($element);
  });

  // define character elements
  $characters = jQuery('.character', $element);

  // interate through character elements for this ngram element
  $characters.each(function() {

    // define this character element
    var $this_char = jQuery(this);

    // define the next character element
    var $next_char = $this_char.next('.character');

    // continue only if there is a next character
    if ($next_char.length) {

      // if this or next character is a space, skip to next character
      if ($this_char.text() == ' ' || $next_char.text() == ' ') {
        return true;
      }

      // define styles for this box element
      var top = -pad + 'px';
      var left = $this_char.position().left;
      var width = $next_char.position().left + $next_char.width() - $this_char.position().left;
      var padding = pad + 'px 0';

      // add absolutely positioned box element
      jQuery('<span>', {
        'class': 'bigram'
      }).css({
        'top': top,
        'width': width,
        'left': left,
        'padding': padding
      }).appendTo($element);

      // increment padding
      pad += 3;

    }

  });

  // remove the positioning elements: .character
  $characters.contents().unwrap();

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
}

.find_bigrams {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 3em;
}

.find_bigrams .bigram {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="find_bigrams">test</span>
<span class="find_bigrams">rhinoceros</span>
<span class="find_bigrams">has some spaces</span>
<span class="find_bigrams">has a unigram</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no

Long answer: Your browser will always treat an ending tag as belonging to the innermost beginning tag. You can work around this by using other tags, i.e. `<span> This <i style="font=style:normal">will</span> override nesting rule</i>`, but this is against W3C spec, and is not guaranteed to work across all browsers because of that (although I suspect it would).

If all you need to do is draw boxes around certain letters, I suggest you use correctly nested `span` tags with different `width` or `padding` values, an image, or the HTML canvas.